# Unable to insert date into database table column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using this query to insert a date value into a SQL Server database table column:

```
INSERT INTO JOB_HISTORY 
VALUES(200001, ('1970/10/01'), ('2035/09/30'), 'IT3', 1003);
```

I get this error:

> Invalid object name 'JOB_HISTORY'.

Comment: Is table [JOB_HISTORY] in the default database schema? Are you sure your connection is connected to the proper database?  Check these things.

Comment: Your database is complaining that it doesn't know what `JOB_HISTORY` is. You have to specify the full path like `INSERT INTO yourdatabase.dbo.JOB_HISTORY` or switch databases with `USE yourdatabase;` before issuing your `INSERT` statement.

Comment: ***Read your error message*** Clearly your problem has nothing to do with the fact that you're trying to insert a date! Learn to focus on what's _relevant!_

Comment: @Faheem The error message is very clear.  How else do you want us to tell you.  Do you have JOB_HISTORY table in the db you are currently in???

Answer (score 0):

Create your script like this:

```
USE yourDatabase; 

INSERT INTO schemaName.JOB_HISTORY 
VALUES(200001, ('1970/10/01'), ('2035/09/30'), 'IT3', 1003);
```

SchemaName might be `dbo` or some other value

Answer (score 0):

Run the following:

```
select  o.object_id, o.name, SCHEMA_NAME(o.schema_id), o.type_desc
from    sys.objects o
where   o.name = 'JOB_HISTORY'
```

The possibilities are as follows:

- No results means your table doesn't exist, or you have the wrong database selected.
- Result returned but `type_desc` is not a table or a view, then you cannot use it as a table.
- Result returned, but SCHEMA_NAME is not `dbo` then you need to explicitly indicate the schema when using the table. If you don't explicitly specify the Schema, SQL Server tries the following defaults.

  - `dbo`
  - The default schema associated with your user.

Specify schema as follows: `[<schema-name>.]<object-name>` E.g.

```
INSERT INTO workshop.JOB_HISTORY
VALUES (200001, '19701001', '20350930', 'IT3', 1003)
```

---

**Side Note** Please observe how I've specified the dates.

- You don't need brackets.
- Use date format `yyyymmdd` (*no separators*). This format Microsoft guarantees to read unambiguously regardless of any other settings.